# Pine Script Trading View Alert frequency

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

In Pine script version 5, while creating an indicator on trading view. I want the alert condition to trigger alert everytime the condition is met, even on the same bar. Currently the alert is triggered only once per bar. Whats the solution to this ?

I tried using the function alert.freqall, however this is not helpful.

I want the alert to be trgiggered every time the condition is true even though on the same bar.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc_on_every_tick` parameter of the strategy function.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, calc_on_every_tick = true)

if barstate.isrealtime
    alert("Tick-tock! Price is changed..", freq =  alert.freq_all)
```

on the realtime-bar with every tick of the price the alert message will be triggered.